# Need to know why the router and the modem have syncing problems after a firmware update

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, sync, wireless-router

I'm on a Netgear N300 router. A few weeks ago I did a firmware update on it and ever since then the router and modem have had some syncing issues. The desktops and wireless devices pick up on the wireless signal but no internet/servers found. I've contacted the cable company and all they say to do is reset the router (unplug router for 10 sec, unplug modem wait 10 sec, plug router in after 10 sec, then plug modem back in.)
 Now this actually does work for a while, but eventually it looses sync again and we must reset the router again. It happens 1 to 3 times a day.
Any idea what the problem here is. The setup was fine for 5yrs then after I did the firmware update this problem started. Any help anyone may be able to give would be much appreciated.

Comment: I would start by reading the readme on the firmware update. It will list some details about the changes that were present in that firmware release (though you might have to look back at all the other updates that you skipped up to this point as well). I see that the N300 is a router/modem combo, so when you refer to syncing, I assume you mean the modem sync with the DSLAM? Or are you hooking another router up to the N300?It would be nice to get a bit more details about the topography.

Comment: The modem was provided to us by WOW! cable and internet.

Answer (score 0):

See if you cant find the old firmware and flash that back. Sometimes downgrading isn't allowed but its worth a try.

Comment: This seems more like a comment since you can't confirm if the problem will be solved using an older firmware.

Comment: He stated that after the firmware upgrade he began having syncing issues. Restoring the old firmware should then solve the problem.

Comment: When you apply a firmware, most of the time, the settings of the device are lost.  I am going to guess the problem is caused by single setting that has been changed back to the default value.

Comment: Ok what if I reset it back to the factory default settings, then just re-entered the settings we preferred? I don't think we did an update before the one I did a few weeks ago. BTW thanks for the responses folks.